# Open a preview image in a dialog when clicking in a imagebutton inside a listview

Tags: android, dialog

I have a listview that displays several images. These images are get throug an adapter. The images are imagebuttons controls. So, what I want to do is that everytime somebody clicks in an image it opens a dialog displaying this image clicked.

Is there any example to review or something similar?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: *"Is there any example to review or something similar?"* there are many but this isn't the place to ask. Try The Google

Comment: Can you provide more information on your listview? Do you have an adapter class or are you using an ArrayAdapter of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to use a new OnClickListener in the setOnClickListener of your ImageButton.
You could pass the image ad myImage to show, and you need to define the Dialog layout on R.layout.dialogbrand_layout

```
button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                  Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ActivityName.this);
                  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogbrand_layout);
                  dialog.setTitle("Image");
                  Imageview myImage = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.myImage);
                  myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimage);
                 dialog.show();
    }
```